# How do I reduct my react application bundle size with webpack, babel, material ui and firebase?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, babeljs

Here is the prod build of my react application.
[image]
Material-ui and firebase auth is taking a big chunk of the size. I followed material UI bundle optimization to only include esm folder and it seems it is working, but I still belive that I ca do better.1.4 mb for material UI seems a lot to me.

Here is my babel config:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "useBuiltIns": "entry", "corejs": 3 }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "corejs": 3,
        "useESModules": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "babel-plugin-transform-imports",
      {
        "@material-ui/core": {
          // Use "transform: '@material-ui/core/${member}'," if your bundler does not support ES modules
          "transform": "@material-ui/core/esm/${member}",
          "preventFullImport": true
        },
        "@material-ui/icons": {
          // Use "transform: '@material-ui/icons/${member}'," if your bundler does not support ES modules
          "transform": "@material-ui/icons/esm/${member}",
          "preventFullImport": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here is my webpack prod config:

```
{
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/App.tsx',
  resolve: { extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', 'jsx' ] },
  module: { rules: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  node: { fs: 'empty' },
  plugins: [
    ProgressPlugin {
      profile: false,
      handler: undefined,
      modulesCount: 500,
      showEntries: false,
      showModules: true,
      showActiveModules: true
    },
    HtmlWebpackPlugin { options: [Object] },
    MiniCssExtractPlugin { options: [Object] }
  ],
  output: { filename: 'static/bundle.[hash].js' }
}
```

Is there anything else I can do to achieve a better bundle size result?